# Using $ anchor inside a character class does not work

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to write a Regex to match a String having 1st 10 characters capital-alpha numeric and then a space and some other text or a String having 1st 10 alpha numeric characters, the `$` does'nt seem to work.

I wrote this `[A-Z0-9]{10}[\s$].*` which seems to work fine for strings having 10 charater then a space and some stuff but not working for string that end just after alpha numeric.

E.g.

```
"MNA345QWRE ABC" gets matched 
"MNA345QWRE" not matched
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$` symbol in `[...]` is treated literally. Use alternation to require either "space followed by something" or "end of line":

```
[A-Z0-9]{10}(?:\s.*|$)
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/f4ufzx/1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need angular brackets for space, try below:

```
System.out.println("MNA345QWRE ABC".matches("[A-Z0-9]{10}(\\s|$).*"));
System.out.println("MNA345QWRE_ABC".matches("[A-Z0-9]{10}(\\s|$)*"));
System.out.println("MNA345QWRE".matches("[A-Z0-9]{10}(\\s|$).*"));
```

Comment: `MNA345QWRE_ABC` sill [matches](https://regex101.com/r/UlyXeh/2), and  it shouldn't.